# Inser list of ids into table aioodbc (pyodbc)

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using `aioodbc` which is basically async pyodbc. My table has only one columns `ClaimID`. I am trying to do bukl insert list of ids like `[1, 2, ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ... n]` (up to 21k)

```
await cur.executemany('INSERT INTO ML.buffer.ClaimListAPI (ClaimID) VALUES (?);', ids)
```

where `ids` is a python list of ints.
I am getting error

```
TypeError: ('Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row', 'HY000')
```

How to perform bulk insert of list of ids ?

Comment: `executemany` needs `[ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ... [n]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executemany` needs `[ [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6] ... [n]]`

So you have to convert it to nested list

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]

ids = [ [x] for x in ids]
```